# Social Media Database Design: Should user-centric tables be created? Or master tables with the relevant data?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to understand, conceptually, the design of a social media site. I've seen on Database Answers that a sample model has a "Me" table, myMovements, myProfiles which I assume are unique to the user (i.e., user Bob has: Bob, bobMovements, bobProfile). But then there are tables such as "Contacts" and "Wall_posts". In this case, are we saying it's fine to put all users' contacts or wall posts into one table and then run a query to select by user_id (I presume this is done to prevent several empty tables that aren't really being used)? Or would those tables be created separately as "Bob_wall_posts"?

Being new to database design, I'm curious as to what type of performance differences (if any) would there be going one way or another; and would there ever be a reason to create "bob_wall_posts" as that would seem like a nightmare to manage?

With that being said if say the contacts table has millions of records as a table like that will grow exponentially, is there a way to build it to optimize performance? Or some method of writing an optimized query?

Below is the model I was referring to.

[image: Social Media Model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamental to relational database design, You would simply not be building data tables for each user...

I don't even think performance issues should be addressed, it's just not done...

Relational databases have pretty fast search optimisation. Just define your keys properly, and use indexes where required and you should be good to go...

Hope it helps